# XSLT 1.0 Getting unique values at node level separately

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

We are trying to get unique values for each node separately using XSLT 1.0. For example,

```
<root>
<node name="1234">
    <node name="9876">
        <child ln="2" name="CA1">
            <CA01>10</CA01>
        </child>
    </node>
    <node name="9876">
        <child ln="2" name="CA1">
            <CA01>9</CA01>
        </child>
    </node>
    <node name="9876">
        <child ln="2" name="CA1">
            <CA01>10</CA01>
        </child>
    </node>
</node>
<node name="1234">
    <node name="9876">
        <child ln="2" name="CA1">
            <CA01>10</CA01>
        </child>
    </node>
    <node name="9876">
        <child ln="2" name="CA1">
            <CA01>5</CA01>
        </child>
    </node>
</node>
```

with the code

```
    <!-- Template called for each node 1234 -->
<xsl:for-each select="node[@name='9876']/child[@name='CA1']/CA01/text()     [generate-id()
                                   = generate-id(key('CA01Code',.)[1])]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

**Expected output**

For first node 1234 => **10, 9**

For second node 1234 => **10, 5**

But actual output when called for each 1234 node gives different output

**Actual Output**

For first node 1234 => **10, 9**

For second node 1234 => **5**

**EDIT** XSLT with Key Definition

Key Definition

```
<xsl:key name="CA01Code" match="node[@name='9876']/child[@name='CA1']/CA01/text()" use="." />
```

Template Definition

```
<xsl:template match="node[@name='1234']">
<xsl:for-each select="node[@name='9876']/child[@name='CA1']/CA01/text()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('CA01Code',.)[1])]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please show us the complete XSLT with the key definition. In general, to restrict searches to a subtree in XSLT 1.0, you can use a key concatenating the generated id of the ancestor e.g. `<xsl:key name="CA01Code" match="CA01" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::node[last()]), '|', .)"/>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin for quick response. Updated key definition and template definition. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:key name="CA01Code" match="node[@name='9876']/child[@name='CA1']/CA01/text()" use="." />
```

to

```
<xsl:key name="CA01Code" match="node[@name='9876']/child[@name='CA1']/CA01" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::node[last()]), '|', .)"/>
```

and then the template to

```
<xsl:template match="node[@name='1234']">
<xsl:for-each select="node[@name='9876']/child[@name='CA1']/CA01[generate-id() = generate-id(key('CA01Code',concat(generate-id(ancestor::node[last()]), '|', .))[1])]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```